# Always display specified number of decimal places in Excel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I need to display two decimal places in Excel (xlsx). I'm using [`PHPExcel`](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/downloads/get/212184). In PHP, I can use something like the following to display only the specified number of decimal paces.

```
echo sprintf("%0.2f", $row['price']);
```

which always displays two decimal places even though the value contains no decimal point i.e if the value of `$row['price']` is `1500`, it will echo `1500.00`. I need to write the same value to excel. I tried

```
$sheet->setCellValue("A1", sprintf("%0.2f", $row['price']));
```

but it displays `1500` instead of displaying `1500.00` (because Excel automatically assumes it to be a numeric value and the part after the decimal point i.e `.00` in this case is truncated).

I also tried the following

```
$sheet->getStyle("A1")->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0.00');
```

but it's not sufficient to achieve what is specified.

How can I (always) display the specified number of decimal places in Excel using PHPExcel?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
$sheet->getStyle("A1")->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0.00');
```

should work, as long as the value in cell A1 is a number and not a formatted string... don't try to force Excel formatting by using sprintf, simply use the format codes.

Comment: is it ok to use setFormatCode('###,###,###,##0.00'); to add commas to the mix or there a better way?

Comment: It's perfectly valid to us setFormatCode('#,##0.00'); to indicate using a thousands separator - or pretty much any format code that MS Excel itself uses

Answer (score 5):

Formatted as number with comma. Assuming that value is not exceeded by 9 digits.

```
$sheet->getStyle("A1")->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('###,###,###.##');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this:

```
$sheet->setCellValue("A1",sprintf("%0.2f",$row['price']),true)->getStyle()->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER_00);
```

Adding 'true' at setCellValue, you refer directly to the cell instead of the worksheet and you can call the getStyle method without the cell value.

Answer (score 3):

If you want some special characters just use html_entity_decode:

```
$currencyFormat = html_entity_decode("€ 0,0.00",ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->getStyle("A1")
            ->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode($currencyFormat);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('ce')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0.00');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try that:

```
$sheet->getStyle("A1")->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('### ### ### ##0.00');
```

it works.